# Facebook Apprequest from Phonegap

Tags: jquery, facebook, mobile, apprequests

I have built a jQuery Mobile project that works great on mobile web. We have loaded it into Phonegap and everything is working **except** for the Facebook **apprequests** function using the JavaScript SDK.

It appears that it is never getting to **//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=placeholder** (placeholder added to hide our app ID) because everything is relative/local.

If we prepend the URL with **http:** we get to Faceboook but get the error:

**Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.**

I suspect that the issue is that Phonegap development runs locally. Is there a way to get around this without using the Phonegap Facebook plugin?

Comment: I should have noted that we are doing this for iPhone / iOS.

Comment: what happened if you add https ?